# an error occurred in the upload. please try again later (Maybe File Permission Issue)

Tags: images, uploads

I have two user roles: admin and author. I cannot upload an image in frontend by using an author account as I receive an error message `an error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.` But it works fine with the admin account. I've tried to login with the admin account to upload an image in frontend and it works. So I think it's the file permission issue. In the setting, I already selected author as the role. And I already tried uploading different images, even small sized images, but it's the same. So I think it's a file permission issue. How can I fix this? I've searched on the internet and they instruct to right click on the folder `uploads` to change the value to 744. But how can I do that in WampServer.

Comment: It is not the issue of file permission As we file permissions are alwas 777 in wamp. and if it would be issue of file permission you would not be able to edit from admin even. Please give some more informatiom how have you implemented the code for frontend upload.

Comment: Hi, I use plugins to allow users submit content in frontend, using shortcodes added in pages. I have a submission form to allow users submit posts in frontend. I have a Q/A plugin to allow users submit questions like this website. But all have the same issues. I cannot upload an image.

Comment: Is it on your pc ? I mean are you using windows OS

Comment: Yes, I'm using Windows OS. After disabling all the plugins and switching to the default theme, I've found the problem. The problem is a custom login plugin. If I login via wp-login.php, I can upload an image without any error. But if I login via that custom login page, I get the error even though I use the admin account to login. How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you please let know the plugin you are using

Comment: Ultimate User Pro v.6.1. If you want, I can send you the plugin so that you can have a look into it.

Comment: Sorry, Ultimate Membership Pro v.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Try mysqlcheck -r DATABASE ...

I have faced the same issue with image upload problem. And found out that some database tables was corrupted/marked as crashed for WordPress DB. Thus I run repair over and that solved the problems with image upload.

Comment: How to run the repair for the database tables in WordPress? Any command that can be run from the mysql console ?